# How do I export a multi table database with exceptions?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, phpmyadmin

I am working out of phpmyadmin to export data using an sql.

I have an 88 table database. I would like to export all data to a .csv from 85 of those tables where I am only keeping the rows in which my column Length(`Status`) > 0.

So far I've come up with being able to select all data from a single table. I would like to apply to my entire database except the 3 tables and export it a .csv.

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE LENGTH(`Status`) > 0

Answer (score 1):

Use [SELECT INTO OUTFILE ... WHERE LENGTH(Status) > 0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) for each table.

PHPMyAdmin isn't a tool for complex tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT("SELECT INTO OUTFILE ... FROM ", table_name, " WHERE ...")
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name NOT IN ("not_me_1", "not_me_1", "not_me_1")
      AND schema_name = "my_database_name";
```

That will generate 85 `SELECT` statements.  Copy/paste them into the phpadmin screen that lets you run arbitrary commands.

(And consider learning to use the mysql commandline tool.)

What kind of values do you have in `status`?  `LENGTH(Status) > 0` seems like a strange test.  Also, beware of `NULL` values; learn about `IS NULL`.